# trailing slashes, routing me to a different page in next.js

Tags: next.js

I am using nextjs to enable SSR in my application. Application structure is:

- components -

  - component1.js
- public -

  - img1.png
- pages -

  - /order
    [order].js
  - [country].js
  - contact-us.js
  - review.js

if I do 'localhost:3000/contact-us/' ,it routes me to [country].js.
I think when we do /contact-us/, it consider it as folder,  but folder is not really there it takes first page that comes in that directory.

I have tried using exportTrailingSlashes: false in next config but it did not help.

Answer (score 0):

I think the best way to avoid this would be to put your `[country].js` page in a `/countries` folder. That'll make your pages look like:

```
pages -
  /order
    [order].js
  /country
    [country].js
  contact-us.js
  review.js
```

Then you can get to the country endpoint via `http://localhost:3000/country/[country]`.